# Verilog code to drive a signal high always

Tags: vhdl, verilog, vlsi, rtl

I am learning Verilog fundamentals recently. I want to drive a signal always high using reg. I wrote this and it didn't work.

```
    reg b;
    always@* 
    begin
       b <= 1'b1; 
    end
```

b is always 'X' in simulation.

In VHDL, I was able to do similar thing:

```
signal b: std_logic;
process(all)
begin
b <= '1';
end process;
```

b is always high in simulation.

I know we can do this using assign statement with wire. But, is it not possible with reg ?

Comment: "always high" and "using registers" makes little sense.

Comment: I am just trying to learn the difference between reg and wire types in Verilog. I learnt that 'reg' can be used to design combinational circuits like gates. So I think it does not always mean a register. It can be wires too in hardware.

Comment: Just an observation... In VHDL your 'b <=' 1';' should be a concurrent statement and not in a process.

Comment: @TonyM I usually write such signals as concurrent statements. But this snippet also did the same job as the concurrent statement when I simulated. I used VHDL-2008.

Comment: It will indeed achieve the same but simpler and clearer is aways better. Easier to read, easier to follow :-)

Comment: There's a distinction between VHDL and Verilog to.do with initialization that affects signal assignment. VHDL executes each process at least once. First during initialization then potentially during subsequent simulation (and that's not the case here, there are no signals being evaluated here, the sensitivity list derived from the reserved word **all** is an empty set). For the Verilog implementation you get initialization using an initial statement as in Dave Tweeds answer. (In VHDL you'd declare b as a constant instead.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `always` block works only if there's something to "trigger" it. In your example, there were no variables on the RHS of any statements, so `@*` effectively reduces to null.

Of course, `initial` would have worked just fine ... or `always begin` (without the `@*`).

And don't forget that you don't *need* to use `begin/end` with `always` or `initial` — if you have only a single statement, it's perfectly valid to write

```
reg b;
initial b <= 1;
```

or

```
always @(posedge clock) data_pipe <= data_in;
```

---

From your comment:

> I am just trying to learn the difference between reg and wire types in Verilog. I learnt that 'reg' can be used to design combinational circuits like gates. So I think it does not always mean a register. It can be wires too in hardware.

No, `reg` does NOT mean "register". It's a very confusing part of Verilog syntax.

Basically, `reg` variables can be assigned to in process blocks (`initial` or `always` statements), while `wire` variables are assigned to outside such blocks (`assign` statements, module port connections, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

In Verilog, you can write

```
reg b = 1;
```

And then never make another assignment to it. But that's not a good coding strategy. SystemVerilog simplified the rules and does allow a single `assign` statement to a variable. You should read [this article](http://go.mentor.com/wire-vs-reg).

Comment: Hm, so are you saying that we cannot do the same in always block ?

Comment: You can, but only if there's something to "trigger" the `always` block. In your example, there were no variables on the RHS of any statements, so `@*` effectively reduces to null. Of course, `initial` would have worked just fine ... or `always begin` (without the `@*`).

Comment: Again, SystemVerilog solves this by replacing `always @*` with `always_comb` which guarantees to trigger at least once at time 0.

Comment: Again, the OP is not asking about SystemVerilog, just plain Verilog.

Comment: @dave Oh okay.....then I think that's it ...In VHDL, process block always executes atleast one time though at the beginning. I thought it works like the same in Verilog.

Comment: @DaveTweed, I realize that. It helps to explain the problems in Verilog that have been solved by SystemVerilog. And many people still don't realize after 15 years that it's an option available to them.

Comment: @dave_59, I'd like to point that SystemVerilog is not always an option.  For example, to program the Xilinx Spartan 6 you cannot use SystemVerilog since it is not supported in Xilinx ISE.

Comment: @ShashankVM, My posted solution is Verilog. The comments on SystemVerilog are about getting to a solution that more closely matches what can be done in VHDL.

Comment: @dave_59, thank you for your reply. Now I understood your comment.